# Any() Linq Method making several queries on the same object. C# EF CORE

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I made several searchs and I'm still struggling with this. 
I want to perform this query on EF core, using sql server Exists():

The problem is, that in sql server the query below takes like 2 seconds to perform. And on C#, using the Any() method it takes more then 1 minute. It makes 
several queries on HutOperationHistory and HutPropertyValue tables.

// takes 1-2 secs

```
select * From Hut h where exists(
    select 1 from HutOperationHistory 
             where HutId = h.HutId and HutOperationId = 4
)
and exists(
    select 1 from HutPropertyValue 
             where HutId = h.HutId and Value = 'HUT_SUPPLIER_PROPERTY_NAME'
)
and exists(
    select 1 from HutPropertyValue 
             where HutId = h.HutId and Value = 'BUY_ORDER_PROPERTY_NAME'
)
and exists(
    select 1 from HutPropertyValue 
             where HutId = h.HutId 
             and Value = 'WORK_ORDER_PROPERTY_NAME'
)
```

I made it on linq and it goes like this:

```
// takes more then 1 minute



  var huts = coreDbContext.Huts
        .Include(x => x.PropertyValuesList).ThenInclude(y => y.HutProperty)
        .Include(x => x.OperationHistoriesList)
        .Where(
            x => 
             x.OperationHistoriesList.Any(
                z => ( z.HutOperation.hutOperationId = 4 )
            )
            && x.PropertyValuesList.Any(b => 
                    b.Value.Equals(hutSupplierPropName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)                  
                )
            && x.PropertyValuesList.Any(b =>
                b.Value.Equals(buyOrderPropName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)             
            )
            && x.PropertyValuesList.Any(b =>
                b.Value.Equals(workOrderPropName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)                
            )
        )
        .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
        .ToList();
```

Is there anything i can do make it faster?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Could you do INNER JOINS instead of where clause?

Comment: I cant do those kinds of INNER JOINS on linq. I need to use something similar to exists()

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific as to why you can not use inner joins?

Comment: Instead of chaining those `&&`, have you looked at putting `hutSupplierPropName`, `buyOrderPropName` and `workOrderPropName` in an array and using `array.Contains(b.Value)`?

Comment: Robert, I can't use JOINS cause I need to pass those conditions. And as far as I know, i cannt do that using the Include() method. At least not when my object to be included is a List<>

Comment: You probably shouldn't have the includes at all, unless you need your returned object to have all those properties filled out.  But then you aren't comparing apples to apples this way.  Your original SQL query isn't returning all the data from each of those tables, but you are forcing your LINQ query to.

Comment: EF is optimized for the "most common" case.  It's also pretty much a black box.  So if you don't like how it generates the SQL from LINQ, then you can write your own SQL and just use the ORM portion of EF.

Comment: I agree with Sam Axe, just copy pasta your actual sql and feed it to EF and execute the query rather than leverage LINQ.

Comment: Remove all `Include` / `ThenInclude` and use `==` instead of string `Equals` with `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` (which most likely is causing client eval) and you'll get comparable LINQ query translation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Any(), try Count() > 0. I have had performance gains using this in the past